# What do the different shape units mean in kinect?

Tags: c++, kinect

Each shape unit or face deformation is meant to indicate some feature of the face being tracked.

In total kinect 2 gives 94 shape units or deformations using HD face API, however it is unclear what the individual shape units indicate and what does their weights signify, the documentation on the subject seem to be either absent or extremely obsecure.

[Here is the full list of shape units or face deformations for Kinect 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.face.faceshapedeformations.aspx)

what is not explained is what things like `FaceShapeDeformations_PCA01` or `FaceShapeDeformations_Eyes02` mean?

As you can see the description table is empty! How shameful and pathetic.

for example:

- What information does the enumeration `FaceShapeDeformations_Eyes02`
  indicate?
- Does it indicates width between the eyes or the height of
  the eyes ?
- What range is covered by its weight from -2 to 2?
- What are cryptic enumerations like `FaceShapeDeformations_PCA01` to `FaceShapeDeformations_PCA10` ?

Does anyone know about this?

Comment: Nobody knows ...?